# Push View Controller - Button Action sending from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pushviewcontroller

I am looking to make an action from a button to another view coontroller.
When the button is pressed, the user is sent to another view controller.

However, when running the simulator and clicking the button, it is not going to the next view controller. (The next view controller is Dashboard).

Here is the .h file and .m file

```
`//  ViewController.h
//  Shopping List
//
//  Created by Seenu on 2/8/16.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Login;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailTextfield;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Password;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

- (IBAction)SignIn:(id)sender;


@end`//

//
//  ViewController.m
//  Shopping List
//
//  Created by Seenu on 2/8/16.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Dashboard.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize button;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
- (IBAction)SignIn:(id)sender {
Dashboard *home = [[Dashboard alloc] initWithNibName:@"Dashboard" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: did u connect the button action properly ?

Comment: does your view controller have a navigaiton controller ?

Comment: Are you using storyboards ?

Comment: yes, I connected the button properly, I am using storyboard, what is navigation controller?

Comment: whithout knowing it, you have the code self.navigationController ? I suggest you to read some basic tutorials regarding the navigation controller and setting the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view controller have navigation controller. An easy way of doing this is create navigation controller in your applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your AppDelegate Class. Set your first view controller as rootViewController of navigationController and add it to window. Go to your AppDelegate Class and add this code over there.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *rootController = 
         [[RootViewController alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                 initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] 
        initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: I am getting an error: "Unknown receiver" - "RootViewController" - did you mean "UIViewController"?

Comment: yes it is UIViewController.....he meant to say it should be your root view controller.

Comment: Instead of UIVIewCOntroller, use your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, just **right click** (or hold down **control button + click**) at your **button** then **drag** to the **view controller** you want to navigate. When option menu showing, select "**Show**".

Also in your storyboard, please ensure that your view controller has embedded in a `UINavigationController`. (Select your first view controller, in Xcode menu click `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`).

*Sorry, I wrote this answer instantly, if you need some picture, I can attach it in the next update*.